# Seeking a one-line command (v. 10) to solve for x[s_] and y[s_] in the following equation: 3x+4y=1+5s. The answes are x=-1+3s and y=1-s

Tags: equation-solving

Seeking a one-line command (v. 10) to solve for x[s_] and y[s_] in the following equation: 3x+4y=1+5s.  The answes are x=-1+3s and y=1-s.

Comment: How do you get two solutions from one equation?

Comment: @Ninos: There are infinite solutions. You have $$3(a + bs) + 4(c + d s) = 1 + 5s$$ We get $$3 a + 4c = 1 \\ 3b + 4d = 5$$ $c$ and $d$ are free variables - choose whatever you'd like and then solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You can get them with `sol = First[SolveAlways[3 (a + p s) + 4 (b + q s) == 1 + 5 s, s]]` then choose any b,q you want to find a particular solution. Choosing b==25, q==-64 we have `{b -> 25, q -> -64, a -> -33, p -> 87}`. You can then check the result easily with `Simplify[3 (a + p s) + 4 (b + q s) /. Join[#, sol /. #] &@{b -> 25, q -> -64}]`

Comment: since there are lots of integer u,v satisfied 3u+4v=1,we can set x=(1+5s)u, y=(1+5s)v. For example,we assume u=-1,v=1,so x=-(1+5s),y=1+5s

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments there are infinite solutions. Perhaps you are looking for the "minimal" solution?

```
Minimize [{x^2 + y^2, 3 x + 4 y == 1 + 5 s}, {x, y}] // Simplify
(*{1/25 (1 + 5 s)^2, {x -> 3/25 (1 + 5 s), y -> 4/25 (1 + 5 s)}}*)
```